# VB.Net And Access: Can't Save Data If I Delete Rows

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I have this problem where I can't save data from a datagridview to my access database file if I delete a row, and the counts are different (e.g. Database file row count is 3, but the datagridview row count is 2). If I have the same amount of rows in both tables, then the data is saved properly. This problem has been hounding me for the past 2 days, so I decided to ask here.

What seems to be the problem in this program?

Here is the code for saving data:

```
                If tbl_inv.Rows.Count > u Then
                    For x = tbl_inv.Rows.Count To u - 1
                        Dim oldRegionRow As POS_Database.InventoryRow
                        oldRegionRow = POS_Database.Inventory.Rows.Item(x)
                        oldRegionRow.Delete()
                    Next
                End If
                Try
                    Me.Validate()
                    InventoryBindingSource.EndEdit()
                    InventoryTableAdapter.Update(Me.POS_Database.Inventory)
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Saved!", "Saved!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
                    Changes = False
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Error Saving!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try
```

Note: I can trick the data into "saving the data" if I add POS_Database.AcceptChanges(), but it still does not properly save, just displays the "Data Saved!" message, but does not actually save the changes in the file itself.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The problem is that the data does not save if there is a difference in row counts on both datagridview and access database. Ignore the Changes = False line as well, because that one works properly (but it is for another button).

Comment: We need to know what actually happens.

Comment: If that `For` loop is supposed to be looping backwards then you need to specify a negative step, e.g. `For x = tbl_inv.Rows.Count To u - 1 Step -1`. If it's not supposed to be looping backwards then your logic is wrong because it can't ever loop forwards based on the `If` statement.

Comment: So what happens is that that section of the code saves the data from the gridview to the access database. However, the problem happens when I delete a row, thus decreasing the row count. Whenever that happens, it ceases to save, and instead goes to the error message.

Comment: Also, the u variable is actually the initial row count value. so it does not count backwards. Changed the condition to < instead of > to avoid possible indexoutofrange errors.

Comment: It doesn't just "go to the error message".  It throws an exception, but you are ignoring all the diagnostic information that that exception contains.  You're supposed to examine that exception to see what went wrong.  That then tells you what to look for in the code or the data while debugging.  That's the theory, anyway.

Comment: The message that displays is "Error Saving!", the one in the try-catch exception bit. Other than that, nothing displays.

Comment: Also, the error only appears when the row counts (number of rows) in datagridview and access database are different.

Comment: *"Other than that, nothing displays"*. Of course nothing else displays. You're displaying that and nothing else. You need to actually look at the exception that was thrown. With your eyes. `ex` is that exception.  You should pretty much always, if nothing else, have `Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString())` in every `Catch` block and that will then write all the information contained in the exception to the Output window. The message that you, as the developer, display is for the ned user. You're not the end user. You need to look at all the diagnostic information the system generates.

Comment: Sorry about that. Found the exception. It says that Update needs a valid DeleteCommand. Same exception as in my other attempts to fix this. Realized that I don't have a proper command for delete in my dataset. Fixed it. Thanks for the help.